# Accept user input from Activity

Tags: java, android

I have some experience with Java, but I am now trying to create an Android app and I do not know how to accept user input. The id of my Edit Text is enterRequestMessage and the name of my XML file is activity_score_entry.xml. Here is the beginning of my Java file.

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class ScoreEntry extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_score_entry);

   }
}
```

Comment: When do you want to get the user input. onValueChange or on button click

Comment: Oh, I forgot. I want to get it on button click of this button: Enter                                    Thanks so much for any help

Comment: set onClickListener() on the button and check the value of EditText. by the way you know findViewById() don't you

Comment: no, I'm sorry I don't. I have written in java but I am brand new to using Java for Android app development

Comment: Ok, I set onClickListener() to my button. Now how do I check the value of Edit Text?

Comment: Please let me know if my answer was helpful by making it as answered or just keep asking and I'm going to help

Comment: Seems like you should be checking out the official Android tutorials rather than coming to StackOverflow. You'll find your answers quicker there for beginner stuff

Comment: Thanks so much, it worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get access to the controls in the xml

```
public class ScoreEntry extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private EditText editText;
    private Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_score_entry);

        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        button.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (view.getId() == R.id.button) {
            String value = editText.getText().toString();

            // use the value here
            Log.d(ScoreEntry.class.getCanonicalName(), "The value is: " + value);
        }
    }
}
```

And in the xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/activity_score_entry"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

You can adjust the code according to your needs.